# Update a field with a counter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table in Oracle like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| KA_ACTEUR  | NIF         | NIF_EXT |  NAME     |    LASTNAME  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| AAAAAAAA1  | 123456789X  | 1       |  JHON     |    DOE       |
| AAAAAAAA2  | 123456789X  | 2       |  JHON     |    DOE       |
| AAAAAAAA3  | 123456789X  | 3       |  JHON     |    DOE       |
| AAAAAAA34  | 123456789X  |         |  JHON     |    DOE       |
| AAAAA6AA5  | 123456789X  |         |  JHON     |    DOE       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
The field NIF is the Primary key
```

And I want to update the entries with the field EXT empty continuing the sequence (max+1).
I used the following code but there are a lot of entries and It takes a lot of time.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR clientCursor IS
      SELECT * from my_table
      where nif_ext is null;
BEGIN
   FOR client IN clientCursor LOOP
      UPDATE my_table
      SET    nif_ext = (select nvl(max(nif_ext)+1,1) from my_table where nif=client.nif)
      WHERE  ka_acteur=client.ka_acteur;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Do you know another way to resolve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is NIF the primary key (unique and not null) or is it the field of interest for which you want to do some math?

Comment: ka_acteur is the primary key,

Comment: My fault @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve using a `merge` statement:

```
merge into my_table
using 
(
  select ka_acteur, 
         (select max(nif_ext) from my_table) as max_nif,
         row_number() over (order by ka_acteur) as rn
  from my_table
  where nif_ext is null
) t on (t.ka_acteur = my_table.ka_acteur)
when matched then 
   set nif_ext = t.max_nif + t.rn;
```